# quantized energies for a particle in a non-linear potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, non-linear-systems

Okay, so the question i'm trying to solve is to find the quantized energies for a particle in the potential:

$$V(x)=V_0 \left ( \frac{b}{x}-\frac{x}{b} \right )^2$$

for some constant b. I used the schrodinger equation with the substitution $$\psi=\frac{\tilde \psi}{\sqrt{x}}$$ as well as $\tilde x=bx$(to make it unitless) and substituted it into the schrodinger equation and obtained
$$ \tilde \psi''- \tilde \psi' x^{-1}+ \tilde \psi \left (\frac{3/4+V_0}{x^2}+V_0x^2-(E+2V_0 \right)=0 $$

Then, I followed along with the derivation in pages 51-56 of Griffiths quantum textbook, by finding an integrating factor and trying to expand $\psi$ as a power series which led me to the following
$$\psi(\tilde x)=f(x)e^-\frac{\tilde x^2}{2} \quad \text{Eq 2.77 in Griffiths 2nd ed}$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nC_nx^{n-1}$$
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)C_nx^{n-2}$$

This of course leads to $$\tilde \psi= f(\tilde x)e^{-\tilde x^2/2}$$
$$\tilde \psi '=e^{- x^2/2} (f'(x)-xf(x)) \quad \text{(dropped the tilde on the x) }$$
$$\tilde \psi ''=e^{-x^2/2}(f''(x)-2xf'(x)+f(x)(x^2-1))$$

I believe these are the correct $\psi$'s however my problem now is when I sub them back into the schrodinger equation I found above, I dont get the same cancellation that happens for the SHO, so I am struggling to find the recurrence relations in order to find the quantized energies. If anyone can help me find the energies I would be much appreciative.

Comment: Offhand I'd wonder if this has a closed form of the sort you're trying to find.  I suspect you're heading deep into the realm of [hypergeometric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation), from whence none return sane. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, im pretty sure this problem has a closed form solution, I dont think I have to invoke hypergeometric equations for it, although it may be a tool of interest for down the road....

Comment: Might be worth asking Mathematics SE for an opinion.

Comment: Please fix your third equation. It's unreadable

Comment: My apologies, its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Well, the standard practice is to pick coordinates suitable to one of the two minima of your potential; taking *b*,
$$
y\equiv x-b \qquad \Longrightarrow \quad V(y)=V_0 \left ( \frac{b}{y+b}-\frac{y+b}{b} \right )^2 \sim \frac {4V_0}{b^2} ~y^2 +...
$$
for large *b*, so you have a bland  oscillator.

Is your assignment to study tunneling to the other minimum?

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I was actually able to figure it out by setting V_0=1, the spectrum then coincided with the simple harmonic oscillator and was relatively straightforward, Tunneling was not something I was concerned about

Comment: Then, if the answer is useless, delete the question.